# Accessing $_POST variables cause errors

Tags: php, variables

I was wondering if you could help me with the following:

I am passing some information filled in a form to the next page to show. I am using `$_POST` method. Although the information is shown in the browser when checking the code is shows an *Notice: undefined index* error and there is no trace of the value passed where it should be (in code). I think this is related to the error above.

The way I am calling it is for ex:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Also I am trying to get the same information in some hidden fields in order to store them (after viewing the page) in a database but here as well there is no value passed. The value in the hidden is empty.

Sorry if this seems a silly thing...but staked and don't know what I am doing wrong.
Really appreciate any help. Many thanks Francesco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP you can not read-access variables that don’t exist. For non-existing normal variables like `$foo` or `$bar` you will get a *Undefined variable* notice, for non-existing array indices like `$array['foo']` or `$array['bar']` you will get a *Undefined index* notice and for non-existing object properties like `$object->foo` or `$object->bar` you will a *Undefined property* notice.

This is because in PHP variables must be declared before a read-access can be done. PHP has the function [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to test if a variable exists, [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) for array indices and [`property_exists`](http://php.net/property_exists) for object properties. Furthermore `isset` is some kind of universal tool to test the existence. (Note that the value *null* is equivalent to not existing.)

So in your case you should test if `$_POST['name']` exists before trying to read it:

```
if (array_key_exists($_POST, 'name')) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
// or
if (isset($_POST['name']) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
```

But note that the existence of `$name` now depends on the existence of `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo for your feedback, although I still not sure what I am doing wrong. I get a warning using isset. Does this mean that the values are wrongly posted?

Comment: @francesco: Whenever you want to read variables whose existence you are not sure of you need to test is with `isset`. Take a look at the examples I’ve posted where `$_POST['name']`’s existence is tested before I read its value. But now `$name` depends on `$_POST['name']` and you would need to test if that variable exists too whenever you want to read it. Or you declare `$name` with a default value (e.g. *null* or `""`) and overwrite it only if `$_POST['name']` exists.

Answer (score 1):

For debug purposes you can try:

print_r($_POST);

It will show all the variables in a post array. 
Look if your variable is in there, if not - there is something wrong with your form.

Leonti

Comment: Thank you Leonti. The variables are there. As said above the value are actually shown into the page thus they are passed.

Comment: Then they are being unset somewhere or the values you see on the page are not from the $_POST var.